# How to Parse JSON file and Collect Data and save into a Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a JSON file it's format is : an array of objects. Each object represents one class. Each JSON object has a "methods" key, representing all methods of the analyzed class. The format is straightforward, as we can see in the following example
THis is not the complete JSON file it's a block for one class

```
[
  {
"methods": [
  {
    "parametersTypes": [
      "String"
    ],
    "metricsValues": {
      "ParameterCount": 1.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 1.0,
      "LocalityRatio": 1.0,
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 2.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 1.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "Smiley.Smiley",
    "smells": []
  },
  {
    "parametersTypes": [
      "String"
    ],
    "metricsValues": {
      "ParameterCount": 1.0,
      "CyclomaticComplexity": 8.0,
      "LocalityRatio": null,
      "MethodLinesOfCode": 23.0,
      "MaxCallChain": 0.0
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "Smiley.checkSmiley",
    "smells": [
      {
        "name": "LazyClass",
         "reason": null,
         "startingLine": 3,
         "endingLine": 36
      }
    ]
  }
],
"metricsValues": {
  "PublicFieldCount": 0.0,
  "TightClassCohesion": 0.0,
  "IsAbstract": 0.0,
  "ClassLinesOfCode": 27.0,
  "OverrideRatio": 0.037037037037037035
},
"fullyQualifiedName": "Smiley",
"smells": [
  {
    "name": "LazyClass",
    "reason": null,
    "startingLine": 10,
    "endingLine": 70
  }
]
  }
]
```

I need to collect all the smells on the JSON file and the i will put them into a DataFrame 
I try it for one Class 
This is my code

```
import json  
from pprint import pprint

with open('Testan.json') as f:
 data = json.load(f)
 pprint(data)

for datum in data[0]["methods"]:
  print(datum['smells'])
```

AND THIs is the resut:

```
 []
 [{'name': 'LazyClass', 'reason': 'null', 'startingLine': 3, 'endingLine': 36}]
 [{'name': 'LazyClass', 'reason': 'null', 'startingLine': 10, 'endingLine': 70}]
```

First I need From this List Just the Names ( LazyClass) and then I need to collect data from all the classes JSON File not from the first class .

Any Help please and Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code below you can add all the smells from all the classes contained into `your_classes` list. All the data is stocked into the `df` dataframe. You can access names trough `df['name']`

```
your_classes = ['Testan.json','other_names.json']
your_smells = []
for filename in your_classes:
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for datum in data[0]["methods"]:
        your_smells.append(datum['smells'])

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(your_smells) # Dataframe with all the smells
print(list(df['name'])) # The list of all names from all classes
```